# How to .htaccess 301 redirect only if the final URL segment is empty

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine and it is generating a URL like this when viewing a specific category:

domain.com/index.php/template_group/template/category_URL_indicator/foo_category/

I would like to redirect visitors if they delete the specific category from the final segment of the URL. For example, if they made the URL this:

domain.com/index.php/template_group/template/category_URL_indicator/

I tried an .htaccess 301 redirect but redirecting the shorter URL also redirected the longer URL. That is, if I put this in .htaccess:

```
redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/index.php/template_group/template/category_URL_indicator http://www.domain.com
```

This also redirected the longer URL to become http://www.domain.com/foo_category/ - not what was required... Any suggestions welcome - thanks!

David.

Answer (score 0):

Try using redirect match instead, along with begin/end boundaries:

```
redirect 301 ^index.php/template_group/template/category_URL_indicator$ http://www.domain.com
```